# How to use the attribute value of an element retrieved with jquery in html file?

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask-sqlalchemy, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a bootstrap/flask website, which will display posts. I have a dropdown menu on each post. I need a way for retrieving the id of the post clicked (post.id) using jquery, and sending it to the server-side, so it can be saved in the database. 
First problem, i dont think my jquery script is correct, and second i don't know how to send it to the server side (site.py).

I've only attached some samples from my app, since its quite long and messy.

UPDATE:
I've updated the script using the script provided by Diptox below. But it still saves the comment with post-id = 1, even though Im commenting on other posts.

**index.html - button sample**

```
`<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toogle" aria-expanded="false" id="menu1" p-id= "{{post.id}}" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
     <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

         <li>
              <a name="comment" class="bound" data-toggle="modal"  href="#" data-target="#modal_comment" >
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    Comment
              </a>
         </li>




         <li role="presentation">
             <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ url_for('DeleteIndexedPost', id=post.id) }}">{{ ('Delete') }}</a></li>



         <li role="presentation">
             <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ url_for('MoveToArchive', id=post.id) }}">{{ ('Move to Archive') }} </a></li>
     </ul>
```

**index.html - modal and script sample**

```
      <div class="modal fade" id = "modal_comment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>

                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Comment</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <form action="{{ url_for('comment', id=post.id) }}" role="form" method ="POST">

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" name="comment" value="">

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" name="ID" value="">

                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>                                        
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                                           
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready( function() 
       {
          $('#menu1').click(function() 
          {
            var postid = $(this).attr("p-id");
            $.post("/index/comment/<int:id>",{ postid: postid });
        });
    });
    </script
```

**site.py -sample**

```
@app.route('/index/comment/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def comment(id):





  if request.method == 'POST':
    new_comment = Comment()    
    new_comment.content= (request.form['comment'])
    new_comment.workID= (request.form['ID'])
    new_comment.post = id #This id is wrong (it defaults to 1 every time)

    session.add(new_comment) 
    session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**db.py -sample**

```
class InfoPost (Base):
   __tablename__ = 'Infopost'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   workerID = Column(String)
   title = Column(String)
   message = Column(String)
   time = Column(DateTime)
   comment = relation('Comment', backref='comment')
   arkiv = Column(Boolean)



class Comment(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'comment'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   workID = Column(String)
   content = Column(String)
   post = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Infopost.id'))
```

Comment: For starters, you're not actually assigning a value to the `postid` variable by setting it equal to an `alert` (in your `click` function).  But I think it would be helpful for you to elaborate on why you think your code isn't working.  What are you seeing on the server side?  Or in your browser's web developer tools?  You need to help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. As you might have guessed, I'm kind of new with jquery. I wont be able to work on the code until saturday, but I will try to test some more then :-)

Comment: Hi again, Ive looked at the network tool in the browser after updating the javascript to the one below (posted by Diptox). The comments ar being posted, but the post.id is being set to 1 each time. Do you know if this because Im not doing anything on the server side, that is in site.py?

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() 
{
    $('#menu1').click(function() 
    {
        var postid = $(this).attr("p-id");
        $.post("/index/comment/<int:id>",{ postid: postid });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't test to see if it works just yet, since I cant access my project until Saturday. But if it works then, I will be sure to give you the credit.

Comment: Huhm.. It does post the comment, but the post.id is set to 1 each time, any idea why? Also, Im missing the code on the server side (site.py) to add the post.id to the db along with the data from the form. Do you know how? :)

Comment: Sorry i have no skills on python :(

Comment: Think I found my flaw. I get a "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in my console.

Comment: ahh ok so just load the jquery.js on your html page

add this to the head of your html page : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes thanks, I did , so that error disappeared:) But Im still having trouble with getting the post.id, which defaults to 1 as before.

Comment: i don't really know , i just corrected your jQuery code that's all i did :D